# should bookmark.id return nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

hey guys so i'm having issues adding a Like/Dislike function to my bookmarks on my page.

basically i have a snippet of code given to me that lives in my User model:

```
   def liked(bookmark)
     likes.where(bookmark_id: bookmark.id).first
   end
```

however when i am running the server and clicking on the topic to show the associated bookmarks, i keep getting the

`` undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass ``

my question is... firstly what is going wrong here? and secondly, whats the difference between bookmark_id and bookmark.id?

im pretty sure id doesn't exist for bookmark... and if not... how would i add it?
ive tried via migration, unfortunately nothing great came from that

Comment: You are getting this error because there is no record present in likes table with that bookmark id

Comment: please check `liked` method where it is being called and make sure the argument `bookmark` passed correctly to the method.

Comment: `bookmark_id` is an column name which should be present in likes table and `bookmark.id` it means you are trying to get the id of bookmark object.

Comment: please post your view?

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
 def liked(bookmark)
  likes.where(bookmark_id: bookmark.id).first if bookmark.present?
 end
```

1. You are getting `id for nil:NilClass` error due to object is not present.i.e `bookmark` object is nil.
2. `bookmark_id` is the field name for the `bookmark` class.And `bookmark.id` returns the id of the `bookmark` object, only if the object is present.

Answer (score 0):

`bookmark.id` raises an exception.
Ensure `bookmark` instance is passed to the `liked` method and is not `nil`

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your `bookmark` argument is not nil.

You could try the following code

```
def liked(bookmark)
  likes.where(bookmark_id: bookmark.try(:id)).first
end
```

or an even better version

```
def liked(bookmark)
  likes.find_by(bookmark_id: bookmark.try(:id))
end
```

Above code will return a `nil` object or first `like`

To answer your second question, `bookmark_id` is an column name here for your `Like` model whereas `bookmark.id` is a method call on `bookmark` object.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following.

```
def liked(bookmark)
  likes.where(bookmark_id: bookmark.id).try(:first) unless bookmark.blank?
end
```

Comment: I didn't understand why you have `try` in the `liked` method of bookmark model. Because it is an instance method and will be called when an object is present. And there is no need of `self` there as it is automatically considered.